# Return data from class

Tags: class, return

I'm new and need some advice. I am working on a smart home project and used QT Creator for graphical visualization.

Managed to get the button from QML to Python, but I don't know how to get from the class Foo to the row outside the class to the RESULT ( the value of the button must be in the result ).

Thank you for your help..

```
class Foo(QObject):
    @Slot(str)
    def button_slot(self,button_from_qml : str, ):
        xprint(input_string)
        return button_from_qml
    
result = Foo.test_slot()

print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QGuiApplication()
    foo = Foo()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    qml_file = "main.qml"
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, qml_file)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    engine.rootObjects()[0].button_off.connect(foo.button_slot, type=Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
```

Managed to get the button from QML to Python, but I don't know how to get from the class Foo to the row outside the class to the RESULT ( the value of the button must be in the result ).

[My request - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9pnV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is a different `test_slot()` function in the Foo class (in the future please include all relevant code), this would work. You have to initialize the Foo object before calling a method on it.

```py
class Foo(QObject):
    @Slot(str)
    def button_slot(self,button_from_qml : str, ):
        xprint(input_string)
        return button_from_qml
    
result = Foo().test_slot()

print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QGuiApplication()
    foo = Foo()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    qml_file = "main.qml"
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, qml_file)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    engine.rootObjects()[0].button_off.connect(foo.button_slot, type=Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work that way for me. The terminal tells me ( TypeError: Foo.test_slot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input_string' )

Comment: Your code seems to need a string as an input - you can pass it on as an argument when `test_slot()` is called.